# Как правильно заполнить alt картинок в галерее с точки зрения SEO

Tags: seo, поисковая-оптимизация

Пытаюсь немного оптимизировать для поисковика карточку товара в интернет магазине созданном в Laravel.
Собственно как с точки зрения SEO лучше оптимизировать код отображения галереи учитывая что для каждой картинки писать вручную уникальный ALT нет возможности?

```
<div class="imglist">
    <a data-fancybox="images" href="{{asset('images/'.$good->supplier_code.'/'.$images_arr[0])}}">
        <img src="{{asset('images/'.$good->supplier_code.'/'.$images_arr[0])}}" alt="Большое превью {{$good->title}}" />
      </a>
<div>
@foreach($images_arr as $image)
<a href="{{asset('images/'.$good->supplier_code.'/'.$image)}}" data-fancybox="preview">
<img src="{{asset('images/'.$good->supplier_code.'/'.$image)}}" alt="{{$good->title}}" width="85" />
</a>
@endforeach
</div>
</div>
```

По идее в цикле где перечиляются маленькие превьюшки нужна маленькая картинка Thumb, но тогда поисковик будет думать мол нет больших изображений на странице или я не прав?

Кроме того писать одинаковый alt (название товара) всем превьюшкам тоже не правильно? Добавить какой-нибудь индекс в конце?
Я пытаюсь разобраться с SEO, но тут непонятно и каких-то четких ответов не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно не отвечаю на Ваш вопрос, о том как технически вы реализуете расстановку альтов. Предлагаю изучить схему и принять решение самому.

Какими же должны быть Alt и Title.

**Требования к Атрибуту Alt:**

- содержательный, описывает изображение;
- длиной около 3–5 слов (до 250 символов);
- по возможности должен включать ключевой запрос;
- не должен быть спамным.

*Почему стоит заполнять Alt:*

> 1. учитывается поисковыми системами при ранжировании картинок, а значит, если ваша картинка попадёт в ТОП, – это источник дополнительного трафика;
> 2. будет полезен пользователю, у которого отключены изображения на сайте.

**Требования  к Атрибуту Title:**

- содержательный и описывает изображение;
- длиной около 3–5 слов или до 250 символов;
- по возможности должен содержать ключевой запрос;
- без спама.

*Почему стоит заполнять Title:

> 1. будет полезен пользователю, которому сложно разобраться, что изображено на картинке;
> 2. подсказки Title могут положительно отразиться на поведенческих показателях сайта.

Comment: вы видимо не прочитали мои вопросы. Перефразирую главный вопрос - если я хочу чтобы в поисковике были все **большие** картинки товара, то как мне их так и указывать в галерее? По идее в галерее должны быть лишь превьюшки (thumb-ы) нажимая на которые появляется большая картинка